# Whay i got Error One To One Relation in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel. I try to create model with one to one relation.
But when i go to test it, its give me error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
> constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
> key constraint fails (`belajar_laravel_eloquent`.`wallets`, CONSTRAINT
> `wallets_customer_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES
> `customers` (`id`)) (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `wallets`
> (`amount`, `customer_id`) values (5700000, 0))

What is wrong?

This is my table:

```
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id', 100)->primary();
            $table->string('name', 100);
            $table->string('email', 100)->unique('customer_email');
        });

Schema::create('wallets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('customer_id', 100);
        $table->bigInteger('amount')->default(0);
        $table->foreign('customer_id')->on('customers')->references('id');
    });
```

This My Model:

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function wallet(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Wallet::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
    }   
}
```

This My Model:

```
class Wallet extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function customer(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

This is my test:

```
public function testOneToOneQueryRelation()
    {
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->id = 'Rinam';
        $customer->name = 'Rinam';
        $customer->email = 'RinamSayang@gmail.com';
        $customer->save();

        $wallet = new Wallet();
        $wallet->amount = 5700000;

        $customer->wallet()->save($wallet);
        self::assertNotNull($wallet->customer_id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are not using auto-increment primary key and also key type string so in `Customer` Model set the following property

```
protected $keyType = 'string';
public $incrementing = false;
```

As per Document

> If your model's primary key is not an integer, you should define a
> protected $keyType property on your model. This property should have a
> value of string
>
> Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing integer
> value, which means that Eloquent will automatically cast the primary
> key to an integer. If you wish to use a non-incrementing or a
> non-numeric primary key you must define a public $incrementing
> property on your model that is set to false

Ref : [Primary Keys](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#primary-keys)

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the very clear explanation. It works.